# Analyse ssl error with gradle (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl seems not to be respected)

Tags: ssl, gradle

I wan't to investigate a SSL error happening when resolving a maven-dependency.
In my naivety, I thought this will do the trick.

```
export GRADLE_OPTS=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

But it doesn't. There is no SSL output at all. Also appending

```
--debug
```

Does not help. How can I turn on the SSL log then?

Answer (score 8):

Try creating a file gradle.properties in the project root folder with the contents

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```